# Polylang plugin translation problems

Tags: multi-language, plugin-polylang

I am using **polylang**.

I have certain input values that are stored in options table of my plugin. I have changed those value to **Nepali** language as well. You can see here: https://prnt.sc/ibqcfx

I have a custom post type where those values (shown in screenshot) are used. I have created multiple custom posts on **Nepali** language. If I view **Nepali** post in the front, I don’t see the string for **transportation** in Nepali. As you can see in the screenshot that I have kept equivalent string for the text **transportation**. But the string is not changed to Nepali value on **Nepali** posts.

I have created a support ticket in plugin's support forum but couldn't get any help there.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: do you use the function `pll__` to get the translation ?

Comment: Hello @mmm Thanks for replying. I am getting other strings on the desired language according to the language without using that function. Should I use that function on all the strings? Please help me understand this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: edit your question to add the code you use.